# AngularJS ng-if directive using a function not returning a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

I'm still pretty new to AngularJS.  Following multiple tutorials online, I used a javascript function inside a `ng-if` directive to validate whether a group name already exists in an array.  If it does, the `ng-if` block is skipped for the next `ng-repeat` iteration.  If it doesn't, add the group name to an array and create the `ng-if` block.  This is what the HTML code looks like in the partial:

HTML

```
<span ng-if="checkGroups(service.group.name)">
      <!--Make nested list-->
</span>
```

This is a simplified version of the javascript:

JAVASCRIPT

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    MainApp.controller('MainController', [
        '$scope',
        'Filters',
        'helper',
        '$timeout',
        '$filter',function(
        $scope,
        Filters,
        helper,
        $timeout,
        $filter) {

            var MainCtrl = this;

            //Function to check group array variable
            $scope.usedGroups = [];

            $scope.checkGroups = function(name) {
                var isValid = true;
                for(var i = 0; i < $scope.usedGroups.length; i++) {
                    if($scope.usedGroups[i] == name){
                        isValid = false;
                        break;
                       }
                }
                if(isValid == true){
                   $scope.usedGroups.push(name);
                    console.log($scope.usedGroups);
                }

                return isValid;
            }

        }
    ]);
})();
```

I've used `console.log()` to return the values and I do get an array with the group names inside as well as a true or false value being returned.  The issue is the `ng-if` function seems to only return false.  If I switch the directive function to "checkGroups(service.group.name) == false", it will keep creating the HTML block regardless.  Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the title.  A value is being returned, but it's only 'false'.

Comment: Could you provide some input values and output you want? First time when the array is blank it should return true.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare I have a model called Service that has a Name and a Group Name.  Using an ng-repeat, all the services are being validated by multiple ng-if directives.  One ng-if is if the service is part of a group and from there another to check if the group already exists.  If the group doesn't exist yet, a nested list is created with all the services under that group.  If it does exist, skip over for the next iteration.  It sounds convoluted, but the client specifically wants it so the grouped services appear alphabetically alongside the non-grouped services.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced your service with just a simple array of objects in the controller, since I don't want to create it. But below should do the trick, notice that I flipped the logic around. This will display it only once and will not display it/insert if the object exists already.

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

var MyController = function($scope) {

  // Somewhere in your service
  $scope.service = {
    group: [{
        name: "Foo"
      }
    ]
  }

  //Function to check group array variable
  $scope.usedGroups = [];

  $scope.checkGroups = function(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.usedGroups.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.usedGroups[i] == name) {
        console.log(name + " exists already!", $scope.usedGroups);
        return true;
      }
    }
    $scope.usedGroups.push(name);
    console.log(name + " doesn't exist!\n", $scope.usedGroups);
    return false;
  }
}
app.controller(MyController, "[$scope, MyController]");
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in service.group"> <!-- This is ran three times, just like calling it with three different names, but I put it in the controller to make it accessible -->
      <span ng-if="checkGroups(item.name)">
        {{ item.name }}
        <!--Make nested list-->
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The logic looks sound.  I tried the code in my app and it seems I have the same issue where it's only accepting a false value.  Sorry.  Was going to attach an image, but it sent the comment too fast.  https://imgur.com/wbnRyNl

Comment: @Michael Are you 100% sure that your `service.group.name` has the correct data in it?

Comment: This is what the console is returning for the code, so it seems the groups are being added in: https://imgur.com/HS8WzCR

Comment: I see what your'e saying. My suggestion at this point would be to filter out the duplicates within your `service` so you don't have to check for duplicates. Or create another method to remove the duplicates from the list in the `controller`.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks again for all the help!  I'll try your second method using a custom directive to call the method after the list finishes rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Use the controller reference:

```
MyController.checkGroups(service.group.name)
```